# How to get value from select2 ajax+mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, ajax

guys.
I want to print in the login.php file the final value which user choosed in select2.username.php file. How I should get it? I want to get value like $_POST['user']

P.S. Sorry for my Eng :D

select2.username.php file

```
<?php
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dist/config.php");

   $query = "SELECT `ID`,`Name` FROM `asd` WHERE `Name` LIKE '%".strtoupper($_GET['q'])."%' or '%".($_GET['q'])."%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
   $numCustomer = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if($numCustomer != 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['ID'], "text"=>$row['Name']);
      }
   }
   echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

login.php

```
<form method="post">
    <select class="form-control select" name="user" required></select>
</form>    
        <script>
            $(function () {
            $( ".select" ).select2({   
                ajax: {
                    url: "../dist/scripts/select2.username.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term, // search term
                            page: params.page
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                        // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                        // alter the remote JSON data
                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                minimumInputLength: 2,
            });

            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Use `type: "POST"` within your ajax call and you will get the data in your PHP file as $_POST array.